# Regular representation is indecomposable for characteristic $p$

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose we consider representations $V$ of a $p$-group $P$ over a  field of characteristic $p$. 
If $V$ is an irreducible character, then it can be shown that $V$ is the trivial representation.  However, if $V$ is not irreducible, $V$ may still be indecomposable. I am having trouble proving that the regular representation, which is reducible, is indecomposible. I know that if it were decomposable, then $V$ would have two independent fixed vectors, which I think might lead to a contradiction..

Comment: See Corollary 6.12 in Webb's "Finite Group Representations for the Pure Mathematician" ( http://www.math.umn.edu/~webb/RepBook/index.html ).

Comment: If you want to do it on your own, hint: Prove that every nontrivial $P$-module over a characteristic-$p$ field has a nontrivial $P$-invariant subspace.