# regular representation of a p group over field of characteristic p is indecomposible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, p-groups

I know that the only irreducible representation of a p-group over field of characteristic p is the trivial representation. But I don't know how to prove this one?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345307/regular-representation-is-indecomposable-for-characteristic-p) answer your question? (edit: wrong link)